# Splitting an array of integers

Tags: java

I have this small problem from getting this array of objects to a Vector as it generates java.util.NoSuchElementException I cant find what seems to be the problem. Can anyone point where seems to be the error please here is the code,

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Splitting {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    protected int [] temp;
    Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<Integer>();

    public void split(String input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
        String[] str;
        str = input.split(",");
        temp = new int[str.length];

        System.out.println(str);

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            {

                temp[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                vec.add(temp[i]);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(vec);
        Collections.sort(vec);


        System.out.println(vec);
        Collections.max(vec);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Splitting obj = new Splitting();

        obj.split("12,65,21,23,89,67,12");



    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, an exception usually comes with a line number and a stack trace. You should show us those, they help. Also, I think you want `if (input != null)`.

Comment: @Matt Ball: `Vector` is a `List`.

Comment: @trutheality: thanks, I typed too quickly. In almost all cases `java.util.ArrayList` should be used instead of `Vector`. `Vector` is a legacy type (from JDK 1.0) and is `synchronized`.

Answer (score 2):

May be should be

```
if (input != null)
```

You can convert array to vector simply with followed snippet:

```
vec = new Vector(Arrays.asList(str));
```

Probably, it wouldn't work in your case (because you need to parse string to integer) but in future it's good to know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
if (input == null)
```

Did you mean to have

```
if (input != null)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

May be instead `if (input == null)` should be `if (input != null)`?

Answer (score 0):

use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
String input = "Some very stupid data with ids of invoces like 121432, 3436534 and 8989898 inside";
List<String> l =Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(" ").split(input));
Collection<Integer> c = Collections2.transform(l, new Function<String, Integer>(){
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String s) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }});
List<Integer> l2 = Lists.newArrayList(c);

Collections.sort(l2);
Collections.max(l2);
```